# Call to async endpoint gets blocked by another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tornado

I have a tornado webservice which is going to serve something around 500 requests per minute. All these requests are going to hit 1 specific endpoint. There is a `C++` program that I have compiled using `Cython` and use it inside the tornado service as my processor engine. Each request that goes to `/check/` will trigger a function call in the `C++` program (I will call it `handler`) and the return value will get sent to user as response.

This is how I wrap the `handler` class. One important point is that I do not instantiate the `handler` in `__init__`. There is another route in my tornado code that I want to start loading the DataStructure after an authroized request hits that route. (e.g. `/reload/`)

```py
executors = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)


class CheckerInstance(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.handler = None
        self.is_loading = False
        self.is_live = False

    def init(self):
        if not self.handler:
            self.handler = pDataStructureHandler()
            self.handler.add_words_from_file(self.data_file_name)
            self.end_loading()
            self.go_live()

    def renew(self):
        self.handler = None
        self.init()



class CheckHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        query = self.get_argument("q", None).encode('utf-8')
        answer = query

        if not checker_instance.is_live:
            self.write(dict(answer=self.get_argument("q", None), confidence=100))
            return

        checker_response = await checker_instance.get_response(query)
        answer = checker_response[0]
        confidence = checker_response[1]

        if self.request.connection.stream.closed():
            return
        self.write(dict(correct=answer, confidence=confidence, is_cache=is_cache))

    def on_connection_close(self):
        self.wait_future.cancel()


class InstanceReloadHandler(BasicAuthMixin, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.get_authenticated_user(check_credentials_func=credentials.get, realm='Protected')

    def new_file_exists(self):
        return True

    def can_reload(self):
        return not checker_instance.is_loading

    def get(self):
        error = False
        message = None

        if not self.can_reload():
            error = True
            message = 'another job is being processed!'
        else:
            if not self.new_file_exists():
                    error = True
                    message = 'no new file found!'
            else:
                checker_instance.go_fake()
                checker_instance.start_loading()
                tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(executors, checker_instance.renew)
                message = 'job started!'

        if self.request.connection.stream.closed():
            return
        self.write(dict(
            success=not error, message=message
        ))

    def on_connection_close(self):
        self.wait_future.cancel()


def main():
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/check", CheckHandler),
            (r"/reload", InstanceReloadHandler),
            (r"/health", HealthHandler),
            (r"/log-event", SubmitLogHandler),
        ],
        debug=options.debug,
    )
    checker_instance = CheckerInstance()
```

I want this service to keep responding after `checker_instance.renew` starts running in another thread. But this is not what happens. When I hit the `/reload/` endpoint and `renew` function starts working, any request to `/check/` halts and waits for the reloading process to finish and then it starts working again. When the DataStructure is being loaded, the service should be in `fake` mode and respond to people with the same query that they send as input.

I have tested this code in my development environment with an i5 CPU (4 CPU cores) and it works just fine! But in the production environment (3 double-thread CPU cores) the `/check/` endpoint halts requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to fully trace the events being handled because you have clipped out some of the code for brevity. For instance, I don't see a `get_response` implementation here so I don't know if it is awaiting something itself that could be dependent on the state of checker_instance.

One area I would explore is in the thread-safety (or seeming absence of) in passing the `checker_instance.renew` to `run_in_executor`. This feels questionable to me because you are mutating the state of a single instance of CheckerInstance from a separate thread. While it might not break things explicitly, it does seem like this could be introducing odd race conditions or unanticipated copies of memory that might explain the unexpected behavior you are experiencing

If possible, I would make whatever load behavior you have that you want to offload to a thread be completely self-contained and when the data is loaded, return it as the function result which can then be fed back into you checker_instance. If you were to do this with the code as-is, you would want to await the `run_in_executor` call for its result and then update the checker_instance. This would mean the reload GET request would wait until the data was loaded. Alternatively, in your reload GET request, you could `ioloop.spawn_callback` to a function that triggers the `run_in_executor` in this manner, allowing the reload request to complete instead of waiting.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, so basically you are suggesting that I instantiate an instance of `pDataStructureHandler` and pass it as a result of a function and then fed it back to `checker_instance`? I will try it and let you know the results.

Comment: About your other question, that if `get_response` is awaiting another function or not; Yes it does await another function for the final result.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that, without the code of how pDataStructureHandler works, I would advise that you work to refactor the code such that the function that is being called on a separate thread only receives and returns simple types, like bools, ints, strings, lists, and dicts with no object references. Furthermore, I would advise that the method be a standalone global function, not an instance method. While it may not be the root cause, my instinct is that whenever working with shared state across threads, you invite the kinds of odd behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I guess another question I could ask is does `get_response` make a call through to the underlying C++ code... or does the data get loaded into and queried from the Python code?